# Python script NameError in power bi

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerbi, windows-10, powerbi-desktop

Getting below name error in Power BI-desktop application.Already explored some stack-overflow threads but no help.Thanks in advance.also put same in [Power BI community](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Issues/python-script-integration-issues/idi-p/3291341#M96651).

Please refer below screenshot.

[image]

**Python code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Agent, Resolved)
dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()
dataset.plot(kind='scatter', x='Agent', y='Resolved', color='green')
plt.show()
```

**option tried:**

1. Uninstall and install power BI desktop application.
2. Try with different version of python.
    3. Even tried with python virtual environment but no success

Looks like python and power BI version compatibility issue.

**Error stack-trace:**

```
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Error Message:
Python script error.
<pi>NameError: name 'Agent' is not defined
</pi>

Stack Trace:
JavaScript: Error
Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreServiceCommon.ScriptHandlerException: Python script error.
NameError: name 'Agent' is not defined
---> Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.Exceptions.PythonScriptRuntimeException: Python script error.
NameError: name 'Agent' is not defined

at Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.PythonScriptWrapper.RunScript(String originalScript, Int32 timeoutMs)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Python.PythonScriptHandler.GenerateVisual(ScriptHandlerOptions options)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Python.PythonScriptHandler.GenerateVisual(ScriptHandlerOptions options)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ScriptVisualCommandFlow.RunInternal(Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ScriptVisualCommandFlow.Run(Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.TransformDataShapeResult(QueryCommand transformCommand, SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand command, Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.ExecuteDataQuery(IQueryResultDataWriter queryResultDataWriter, EngineDataModel engineDataModel, DataQuery query, Int32 queryId, ServiceErrorStatusCode& serviceErrorStatusCode, CancellationToken cancelToken)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.ProcessAndWriteSemanticQueryCommands(IQueryResultsWriter queryResultsWriter, IList`1 queries, HashSet`1 pendingQueriesToCancel, EngineDataModel engineDataModel)

Stack Trace Message:
Python script error.
<pi>NameError: name 'Agent' is not defined
</pi>

Invocation Stack Trace:
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace, String exceptionMessage)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.GetStackTraceInfo(Exception e)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<HandleException>b__0()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Utilities.PowerBIFormUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.UIBlockingService.AllowModalDialogs(Action action)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.HostServiceDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<ExecuteOnUIThreadAndHandlePromise>b__0()
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.HostServiceDispatcher.ExecuteOnUIThreadAndHandlePromise[T](Func`1 func, IPromiseStore promiseStore, Int64 promiseHandle)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.WebView2.WebView2Interop.InvokeCs(InteropCall call)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.WindowManager.ShowModal[T](T dialog, Func`1 showModalFunction)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<RunApplication>b__0()
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.IExceptionHandlerExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<HandleExceptionsWithNestedTasks>b__0()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.RunApplication(String[] args)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)


PowerBINonFatalError:
{"AppName":"PBIDesktop","AppVersion":"2.118.621.0","ModuleName":"","Component":"","Error":"Error","MethodDef":"","ErrorOffset":"-1:-1","ErrorCode":""}

Snapshot Trace Logs:
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\FrownSnapShotc7961737-aeb3-43dc-8a36-8ba93ecf010a.zip

Model Default Mode:
Import

Model Version:
PowerBI_V3

Performance Trace Logs:
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\PerformanceTraces.zip

Enabled Preview Features:
PBI_enableWebView2
PQ_WebView2Connector
PBI_sparklines
PBI_scorecardVisual
PBI_NlToDax
PBI_fieldParametersSuperSwitch
PBI_horizontalFusion
PBI_setLabelOnExportPdf
PBI_newCard

Disabled Preview Features:
PBI_shapeMapVisualEnabled
PBI_SpanishLinguisticsEnabled
PBI_qnaLiveConnect
PBI_b2bExternalDatasetSharing
PBI_enhancedTooltips
PBI_angularRls
PBI_onObject
PBI_dynamicFormatString
PBI_oneDriveSave
PBI_oneDriveShare
PBI_gitIntegration

Disabled DirectQuery Options:
TreatHanaAsRelationalSource

Cloud:
GlobalCloud

PowerBIUserFeedbackServices_IsReported:
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got issue actually no need of below lines in python code.

```
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Agent, Resolved)
dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()
```

Its handled internally.Power BI desktop app create temporary folder by name PythonEditorWrapper_XXXX on machine and in same folder data source of pandas frame is present along with python code.

***Screenshot of created folder:***

[image]

New bare minimum code to visualize chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset.plot(kind='scatter', x='Agent', y='Resolved', color='green')
plt.show()
```